# Version strings to "System.Version" too long (or short) in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, directory, system.version

How can I force conversion to type `System.Version` in PowerShell, or more likely, better understand why I cannot arbitrarily assign number strings type `System.Version`?

We ingest some software updates in folders whose titles include version numbers. In trying to get reports on what the latest versions ingested are, I have been doing the following quick and dirty:

```
ForEach ($Folder in $(Get-ChildItem -Path $SoftwareDirectory -Directory))
{
    $CurrentVersion = $Folder -Replace "[^0-9.]"
    If ($CurrentVersion -ne $null)
    {
        If ([System.Version]$CurrentVersion -gt [System.Version]$MaxVersion)
        {
            $MaxVersion = $CurrentVersion
            $MaxFolder = $Folder
        }
    }
}
```

This would be fed directory titles like the following,

- foo-tools-1.12.file
- bar-static-3.4.0.file

Most of the time, this is acceptable. However, when encountering some oddballs with longer numbers, like the following,

- applet-4u331r364.file

In which case, `System.Version` refuses the resulting string as being too long.

```
Cannot convert value "4331364" to type "System.Version". Error: "Version string portion was too short or too long."
```

Comment: Well it makes sense because `4u331r364` is not a valid version string. See [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-6.0#remarks).

Comment: Thanks for that link. What I didn't spot right away (will of course keep looking), is why I can't make the version string theoretically "4331364.0" just for the purposes of comparison. It wouldn't have to be a valid interpretation of 4u331r364 for my purposes, just a quick determination of whether there was a new version.

Comment: @branpurn `[System.Version]` stores the individual revision numbers as 16-bit integers, making the largest possible value `32767`. You'll want to rewrite `4u331r364` to `4.331.364` before attempting to convert it

Comment: In addition, `$(""),$null | Where {$_ -ne $CurrentVersion}` makes no sense, it's not clear what is doing there or why is there

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Actually it is 32-Bit integer per `Version` property (Major, Minor, Build, Revision). Test: `([Version] "$(2GB-1).0").Major -eq (2GB-1)`. Version resources of executable files can only use 16 bits per field, but in this case the version comes from the folder name, so this doesn't matter.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, previously was forcing `System.Version` before this block which caused issues when comparing `$CurrentVersion -ne $null`; don't recall 100% details but will remove the red herring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to ensure that your version strings have at least *two* components in order for a cast to [`[version]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Version) to succeed:

```
(
  @(
    'oo-tools-1.12.file'
    'bar-static-3.4.0.file'
    'applet-4u331r364.file'
  ) -replace '[^0-9.]'
).TrimEnd('.') -replace '^[^.]+$', '$&.0' | ForEach-Object { [version] $_ }
```

The above transforms `'applet-4u331r364.file'` into `'4331364.0'`, which works when cast to `[version]`.

Note that you can avoid the need for `.TrimEnd('.')` if you exclude the filename extension to begin with: `$Folder.BaseName -replace '[^0-9.]'`

`-replace '^[^.]+$', '$&.0'` matches only strings that contain no `.` chars., in full, i.e. only those that don't already have at least two components; replacement expression `$&.0` appends literal `.0` to the matched string (`$&`).

Output (via `Format-Table -AutoSize`):

```
Major   Minor Build Revision
-----   ----- ----- --------
1       12    -1    -1
3       4     0     -1
4331364 0     -1    -1
```